# Dynamic images sorting and cropping similar to google+ album view

Tags: javascript, image, sorting

can someone help me find a solution to achieve the same result as the [google plus album view](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/101378715508975822285/albums/5560984262495021617) ?

The thumbnails listing manages to keep a consistent row width by re-sorting AND cropping images so they fit all the time, and re-arranges them according to window size.

I know about [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) but it tends to create a lot of white space when images don't have the same size... (because it does not handles cropping)

Does anybody knows about a plugin that does that? or if not the basic math behind it?

Comment: +1: wow. thats some algorithm!

Comment: Check this out http://codepen.io/jasonmayes/pen/nmhAt

Answer (score 2):

take a look at:

http://blog.vjeux.com/2012/javascript/image-layout-algorithm-google-plus.html

It explains how the layout works.

Also take a look at:
http://www.techbits.de/2011/10/25/building-a-google-plus-inspired-image-gallery/ 
http://www.moewashere.com/jglance/

which are both implementations of the google plus album grid.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a bit overkill for what you are looking for.

You can use the [Simulated Annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) algorithm, that is commonly used in electronics to find the optimal layout for all the tiny electronic components inside a microchip restricted area, which is basically the same problem of finding the best layout for a set of images inside a browser window.

Basically, this algorithm gives you a good solution but not guarantee to be the best.
Read carefully the Wikipedia article, as it explains better than I would do.

You can also check out this [Simulated Annealing applet](http://www.heatonresearch.com/articles/64/page1.html) for the Salesman problem. Try out with a 500  temperature and watch what happens when it colds down.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What I found in google plus and may be it can help you.

1. They cut some images to make it fit. You easely can find it on the first image
2. They have lines of images with the same height

So it is ease to do that. You can adjust images to the same height by scaling at first and in each line you can cut the widest a little bit to adjust the width of line.

O, by the way, If you will strach chrome window with google+ service it will not look as good as it was, some gaps will apear for some lines